# Help with $readmemb

Tags: verilog, modelsim, system-verilog

I have three variables, x,y,z which acts as an input to my SV model. Each of the input are of 16bit length binary data and I have 500 values of them. I need to supply them as input to my module at every posedge of the clock and each after #20ns delay. This is via the TB and also I need to write the output values into a text file. Can someone help me with code. Here is what I have written.

```
logic [15:0] X,Y,Z;
logic clk, vectornum;

logic [15:0] testvectors [499:0];

or or1(.*);

initial begin
   clk =0;
   forever #5ns clk #~clk;
end

initial $readmemb("xyz.txt",testvectors);

always@(posedge clk)
begin
   #20 {X,Y,Z};
   testvectors[vectornum];
   vectornum=vectornum+1;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Surely you need some thing more along the lines of :

```
#20 {X,Y,Z} = testvectors[vectornum];
```

However `$readmemb` is meant for initialising memories. Reading the file line by line using scanf would seem more appropriate here. This would also be similar syntax used to write the output to a file.

```
integer data_in_file; //file handler
integer i;
integer r_in; //file handler

//input data
logic signed [31:0] dat1_in;
logic signed [31:0] dat2_in;
logic signed [31:0] dat3_in;

initial begin
data_in_file  = $fopen("data.in", "r");
for(i=0; (i<500) && (!$feof(data_in_file)); i=i+1) begin
   #20ns;
   //Expecting 3 decimal numbers
   r_in  = $fscanf(data_in_file, "%d %d %d\n", dat1_in, dat2_in, dat3_in);
end
```

To write a file:

```
integer data_file_out;
logic signed [31:0] a; //Data driven some where else

initial begin
  data_file_out= $fopen("test", "w");
  //place write inside loop
  $fwrite(file, "%b", a); //Wrte a as Binary number 
end
```